# YUI Rich Text Editor Tool to apply Border for Image or div or page?

Tags: yui, border, rich-text-editor

I have requirement, where a user can choose any border for the content he posted in the editor. Is there any sample available to create borders in YUI Rich Text Editor?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,